# Ruby - Overriding string methods in a separate file

Tags: ruby

I have a file, 'example.rb', where I want to use custom methods on String by overriding the string class.

I know this can be done as

```
puts "abcd".twice

class String
  def twice
    self*2
  end
end
```

But I want to have the custom methods definition in another file, say 'my_String.rb'. How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do your monkey patching in "my_string.rb" (or whatever) and have the file `require`d in your script.

```
# my_string.rb

class String
  def twice
    self*2
  end
end


# my_super_script.rb
require 'my_string.rb' # Assuming both these files are in the same folder
puts "abcd".twice
```

Comment: Make sure it's in LOAD_PATH. By default "." is not there, so you might have to use: require './my_string.rb'

Answer (score 0):

You simply put the String class opening method in my_string.rb and in your code you do:

```
require 'my_string'
```